# Remove Slack buttons for respondents, but not the rest of the channel

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have a slack bot wrapped in an app that I'm using to send users in a channel an attachment asking a question with button options. The problem is that when a user clicks a button I seem to only have one of two options:

1. Replace the original attachment for the entire channel, so that only the first respondent counts; or
2. Set the `replace_original` attribute to `false` and have the response show as ephemeral for the respondent, but leave the buttons there for them to continue to click as many times as they want.

What I need is to be able to disable the buttons and acknowledge the click for respondents, but keep the original attachment with buttons intact for those in the channel who have not yet responded. I can't find the answer on Slack's documentation, including:

- [Intro to Message Buttons](https://api.slack.com/tutorials/intro-to-message-buttons)
- [Interactive Messages](https://api.slack.com/interactive-messages)
- [Interactive Messages Field Guide](https://api.slack.com/docs/interactive-message-field-guide)
- [Message Guidelines](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-guidelines)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that are your only options. Slack will not manage the state of each user with respect to your app / this action for you. You will have to do that yourself in your app, e.g. I would go with option 2 and reply with an ephemeral and user specific Messetage after a button is clicked